# How many times is the function evaluated?

Tags: java

If you have a ternary condition like this:

```
(sum(a,b) > sum(b,c) ? sum(a,b) : sum(b,c))
```

Is it efficient and clean to write it this way? Is `sum(a,b)` or `sum(b,c)` evaluated twice? How can I improve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this particular problem, you're probably better off using Math.max() rather than writing out the ternary expression logic yourself.

Comment: @Bozho, @Ralph: Maybe the question is about whether or not ternary operator has *lazy evaluation*. Not this particular usage

Comment: @Goran - perhaps yes, but I thought the answer deserves at least an upvote. :) Perhaps not that many ;)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is evaluated twice (well, there might be some (JIT) compiler / JVM optimization that I don't know of, but you can't rely on that)

Compute the values before the ternary operator.:

```
int sumAB = sum(a, b);
int sumBC = sum(b, c);
sumAB > sumBC ? sumAB : sumBC;
```

Of course, for a simple sum, the difference will be negligible. But it's a good practice in general.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they will be evaluated twice.

You can do this:

```
 int x, y;
 ((x = sum(a,b)) > (y = sum(b,c))) ? x : y;
```

if you really want to use the ternary operator.

Comment: That's not even saving characters (at least not significantly; using a `max` function is propably about the same length or even shorter). It's just wicked.

Comment: @unbeli: The only two good reasons why anyone would want to use the ternary operator are: 1) as you said, to conserve source code bytes, 2) if they want to write their `if else` as an expression to be evaluated. This answer fits both cases. The first one is obvious, and for the second one I even treated assignment as an expression. I guess the question was about exploring a language peculiarity, so this is a peculiar answer.

Answer (score 1):

Seems 'b' is unconditional.

```
sum(b, Math.max(a, c))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it will be evaluated twice, also not easily maintainable. You need to refactor the method calls.